# Using windows' CreateEvent() function from java using JNA

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I've written the following class to wrap the creation of a win32 event object

```
import com.sun.jna.*;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.*;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;

/**
 * Wraps a (newly-created) native win32 event object and allows you to signal it.
 * 
 * The created event object is manual-reset and is initially un-set.
 */
public final class Win32Event
{
    private static final Kernel32 INSTANCE = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("Kernel32", Kernel32.class);

    private WinNT.HANDLE m_handle = null;

    public Win32Event(String in_eventName)
    {
        assert null != in_eventName;

        m_handle = INSTANCE.CreateEvent(null, true, false, in_eventName);

        assert !Pointer.NULL.equals(m_handle.getPointer());
    }

    public void signal()
    {
        assert isValid();

        INSTANCE.SetEvent(m_handle);
    }

    /**
     * @return True if the event handle hasn't been freed with free().
     */
    public boolean isValid()
    {
        return null != m_handle;
    }

    /**
     * Frees the wrapped event handle. This must be done to prevent handle leaks.
     */
    public void free()
    {
        if (isValid())
        {
            INSTANCE.CloseHandle(m_handle);

            m_handle = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize()
    {
        free();
    }
}
```

I'm using jna 3.3 on a windows 7 machine, and when I try to create an instance of this class, I get the following stack trace.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error
>   looking up function 'CreateEvent': The specified procedure could not
>   be found.
>
> at com.sun.jna.Function.(Function.java:179)   at
>   com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:347)     at
>   com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:327)     at
>   com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:203)  at
>   $Proxy0.CreateEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   Win32Event.(Win32Event.java:23)

I'm really new to JNA, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the code from doing `INSTANCE.[method]` with that static variable I defined at the top to instead use `kernel32.INSTANCE.[method]`.

I figured it out by looking at the definition of kernel32 and noticing it had that static INSTANCE variable.

Comment: The `in_eventName` assert is suspicious. Events can be named or unnamed, but to create an unnamed event, you have to pass a null character pointer to the actual `CreateEvent()` DLL function. Does `Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreateEvent()` account for that? Also, in the actual DLL, `CreateEvent()` is exported as `CreateEventA()` for Ansi and `CreateEventW()` for Unicode names. Does `Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreateEvent()` account for that, too?

Comment: For my use case, I always want the event to be named. For your other comment, I can only hope they used the W version, as Java's strings are Unicode

Comment: JNA automatically handles the mapping to "ansi" or unicode and the associated string conversions; see `W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS`, which is used to initialize the `kernel32` library.